# Order by 2 conditions in SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, backend

Is there a way to order everything by 1 condition and then another condition in SQL? For example, I am trying to use the following statement:

```
SELECT * FROM newsDocs ORDER BY id DESC, pin
```

to order the contents of the database by their id (newest at top) and then their pin (which is equal to either 1 or 0, 1 = go on top of everything else, 0 = keep in the normal order).

The above statement only orders the database by id DESC.

I am also using PHP for this.

EDIT:

Visual representation:

current:

"TITLE" (id 17, pin 0)

"TITLE" (id 16, pin 1)

"TITLE" (id 15, pin 0)

target:

"TITLE" (id 16, pin 1)

"TITLE" (id 17, pin 0)

"TITLE" (id 15, pin 0)

Hope that makes more sense. TIA.

Comment: It sounds like you want `pin` ordered descending, then by `id`. Swap the order of your columns in the ORDER BY clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Order by pin first then order by id. Add the DESC to the end

SELECT * FROM newsDocs ORDER BY pin DESC, id DESC

Answer (score 3):

try this, first order by pin then by id

```
SELECT * FROM newsDocs ORDER BY pin DESC, id DESC
```